# Prove $\frac {1 + a + a^2 + \ldots +a^{n - 1} }{n} < \frac {1 + a + a^2 + \ldots +a^{n - 1} + a^n}{n + 1}$ if $1 < a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Prove $\frac {1 + a + a^2 + \ldots +a^{n - 1} }{n} < \frac {1 + a + a^2 + \ldots +a^{n - 1} + a^n}{n + 1}$ if $1 < a$

Tried induction. Not sure where my mistake is, but what I did doesn't seem to make sense:

Let $n = 1.$ Then $1 + a + a^2 + \ldots +1 < \frac {1 + a + a^2 + \ldots +1 + a}{2} = \frac{2 + 2a + a^2+ \ldots}{2} = 1 + a + \frac{a^2}{2} + \ldots$

Then I did this below, but it's unclear if the difference is positive:

$\frac {1 + a + a^2 + \ldots +a^{n - 1} + a^n}{n + 1} - \frac {1 + a + a^2 + \ldots +a^{n - 1} }{n} = \frac {n + na +na^2+ \ldots + na^{n - 1} + na^n - n - 1 - an - a- na^2 - a^2 - \ldots -na^{n - 1} - a^{n - 1}}{n(n + 1)} = \frac{n(1 + a + a^2+ \ldots + a^{n - 1} + a^n - 1 -a - a^2 -a^{n - 1}) - 1 - a - a^2 - \ldots - a^{n - 1}}{n(n+1)} $

$ = \frac{- 1 + a(n(a^{n - 1}) - 1 - a - \ldots - a^{n - 2})}{n(n+1)}$

What can I try now?

Comment: The case $n=1$ seems a bit too complicated, should be just $1<\frac{1+a}{2}$.

Comment: Did you try the sum of a geometric sequence? $1+a+a^2+\ldots +a^n = \frac {a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}$

Comment: @Ennar no, but is $\frac {a^n - 1}{n(a - 1)} < \frac{a^{n + 1} - 1}{(a - 1)(n + 1)}$ easier to prove granted it's an equivalent inequality?

Comment: Well, $a-1$ cancels out, so that form looks much simpler. Haven't tried it, though, but looks promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{1+a+\ldots+a^{n-1}}n<\frac{1+a+\ldots+a^n}{n+1}\iff$$

$$\frac1n\,\frac{1-a^n}{1-a}<\frac1{n+1}\,\frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}\iff$$

$$(n+1)(1-a^n)\stackrel{\text{since}\;1-a<0}>n(1-a^{n+1})\iff-na^n+1-a^n>-na^{n+1}\iff$$

$$n(a^{n+1}-a^n)>a^n-1\iff na^n(a-1)>(a-1)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+\ldots+a+1)\iff$$

$$na^n>1+a+\ldots+a^{n-1}$$

and the last inequality is trivial since $\;a^n>a^k\;,\;\;\forall\,k=0,1,2,...,n-1\;$

Comment: I thank you and everyone else on here.

Comment: I am reading your proof from the bottom up. How do you get the very first line from the top from the second line from the top?

Comment: @JayZ That is the sum of geometric series: $$1+r+r^2+...+r^k=\frac{1-r^{k+1}}{1-r}$$

Answer (score 2):

Multiply both sides on $n(n-1)$  then you can see:
$$na^{n} > \sum_{i=0}^{n}a^{i}$$
Right side is geometric progression:
$$na^{n}>\frac{a^{n}-1}{a-1}$$
Now you can continue by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You have a more general result:

> If $\{a_n \}$ is strictly increasing then also the sequence of the avarages over the first $N$ terms is strictly increasing.

In fact we have
$$
S_N=\frac 1 N \sum_{k=1}^N a_k<\frac 1 N \sum_{k=1}^N a_N=a_N<a_{N+1}
$$
and therefore
$$
S_{N+1}=\frac {\sum_{k=1}^N a_k+ {a_{N+1}}} {N+1}=\frac{N S_N+a_{N+1}}{N+1}>
\frac{N S_N+S_N}{N+1}=S_N
$$

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

Your inequality is equivalent to $\frac{a^n-1}{n}<\frac{a^{n+1}-1}{n+1}$. But this is $\int_1^a x^{n-1}dx< \int_1^a x^n dx$, which is true because $x^{n-1} < x^n, \forall x \in (1, a]$.